# Button command in ControlTemplate inside ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to add Command binding to my button in resource dictionary. I have global style designed for the whole app and all I want is add button with command, that openes on-screen keyboard to all textboxes.
My code below:

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
<Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <ScrollViewer Width="150" />
                            <Popup x:Name="icon" IsOpen="False" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                <Button BorderThickness="1" Visibility="Visible" Command="{*..and now I want to bind my command...*}">
                                </Button>
                            </Popup>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsOpen" TargetName="icon" Value="True" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Can anyone help to solve the problem?

Comment: You are redefining control template of `TextBox` to make it not a `TextBox`, but a something containing `Popup` with a button. What can I say. I have no idea what are you trying to achieve. How about - do not do it?

Comment: it is a textbox but when focused, popup shows (to show button allowing open "osk.exe")

Comment: If I'd be adding on-screen keyboard to all my controls, I'd use attached behavior (to show it on focus). If you want a button - rather make it a user control. I am not sure what to do with view model, but you can organize it as a custom control, without commands, but directly doing something in code-behind on button `Click` event.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a usercontrol containing a textbox with an event handler for the "GotFocus" event starting osk.exe and an event handler "Lostfocus" terminating osk.exe like so:

```
<UserControl [...] >
    <Grid Background="White">
        <TextBlock GotFocus="ShowKeyboard" LostFocus="HideKeyboard"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

    private void ShowKeyboard(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //run osk.exe
    }

    private void HideKeyboard(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //terminate osk.exe
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your button using PlacementTarget

```
<Button BorderThickness="1" Visibility="Visible" Command="{*..and now I want to bind my command...*}" DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

And later in the code you need to specify the tag, it is looking for window, but you can change the anecestorType.

```
<TextBox Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

Of Course in your ViewModel(DataContext) you need to have specified correct command.